# World Painter Custom Object Problem

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been using World Painter recently to make custom terrain for some of my builds. But for my most recent terrain I've made my own custom trees which I've turned into schematics using mcedit. They load successfully as custom objects in World Painter, except I've been experiencing a problem putting them on. The areas of the schematic which I presume were air seem to be affecting the other trees when placed. This ends up with some trees that are completely missing or mostly missing leaves. See photos for an easier explanation. I feel as if there is probably an easy way to stop this but cannot for the life of me figure it out. How can I fix this?

[image: Image of some Minecraft trees missing leaves.]

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so I've somehow fixed this myself. For anyone with the same problem, I did this by using World Edit Schematics instead of MCedit ones.

Comment: You can mark your answer as correct :)